# how to achieve good cardview like layouts in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, frame, cardview

I am using Frames in XAML to achieve card views. But this design is not anywhere close to the Google app card views or any other apps card views. Also, I do not see a nice shadow on all 3 sides instead it has a fake line of shadow

Here is the code:

```
<Frame Margin="0,20,0,0"
                       IsClippedToBounds="True"
           HasShadow="True">
                    <Frame.OutlineColor>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color"
                                    Android="Gray"
                                    iOS="Gray"></OnPlatform>
                    </Frame.OutlineColor>
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
                            <Image Source="mf_tickets1.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Aspect="AspectFill"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <Label x:Name="showsummary" Text="Summary " TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Start" >
                            </Label>
                            <Image  x:Name="SummageHideShowImage1" Source="{Binding SummageHideShowImage}" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"
                               Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" ></Image>
                        </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Is there any other way to achieve good card view layouts to make my app as a premium?

Comment: You can refer this: https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView

Answer (score 0):

I'm little hesitant to use third-party NuGet packages.
I wrote a custom frame Renderer and assigned a drawable resource file with suitable elevation, color, and shadow.

Custom frame:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null && e.OldElement == null)
            ViewGroup.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.FrameRenderValue);
        ViewGroup.Elevation = 6;
    }
```

FrameRenderValue.xml :

```
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />
  <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
</item>
<item
  android:left="0.5dp"
  android:right="0.5dp"
  android:top="0dp"
  android:bottom="0dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
  <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
</item>
```

Thanks